# What's this line in Landsat MSS image?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat

I have a Landsat MSS image file that contains a vertical string of incorrect pixels. Does anybody know what this might be?

[image]

Comment: just a guess, but this could be a contrail

Comment: possible vapour trail from a jet engine (or rocket engine) depending on location as radouxju mentions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_Trail

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include the scene path/row and the lat/long coordinates of the feature we see on the screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, it does not appear on images of the location of other dates, so it cannot be something on the ground - it was just that day. Either an anomaly of some sort on the satellite, or a temporary change in the atmosphere (e.g. weather conditions or a contrail or something).